# Woocommerce Wordpress Adding Images to an Order in Cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, image-uploading

Here's the issue: I am trying to add multiple customer uploaded images to a woocommerce product order.

This is what my current function looks like to generate the fields before the add cart button (This displays properly and allows for a customer to select a file from their computer to upload):

```
function my_special_fields(){
    if (get_the_title() == "My Special Product"){
        echo '<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" name="my_image_upload" id="my_image_upload" multiple="false" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>';
    }
}
```

Which I call with the hook:

`add_filter('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'my_special_fields');`

I then use another hook for adding the item data to the cart:

`add_action( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_my_special_fields', 10, 2 );`

And the function called with that hook looks like this:

```
function save_my_special_fields( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
// I save a lot of fields in here that are working fine so ignoring those for now
// This is where I try and find my file to upload
    if( ! empty( $_FILES ) ) {
        foreach( $_FILES as $file ) {
            if( is_array( $file ) ) {
                $attachment_id = upload_user_file( $file );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It calls this piece of code I found for uploading files into wordpress: https://hugh.blog/2014/03/20/wordpress-upload-user-submitted-files-frontend/

```
function upload_user_file( $file = array() ) {
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );
$file_return = wp_handle_upload( $file, array('test_form' => false ) );
if( isset( $file_return['error'] ) || isset( $file_return['upload_error_handler'] ) ) {
    return false;
} else {
    $filename = $file_return['file'];
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'guid' => $file_return['url']
    );
    $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_return['url'] );
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );
    if( 0 < intval( $attachment_id ) ) {
        return $attachment_id;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Right now I am not assigning to any post or doing anything with the image other than trying to get it to upload so that as an Admin I can view it in my media folder.

I think the issue is that the woocommerce form for the add to cart fields might not have this encoding:

`enctype="multipart/form-data`

Any help on implementing this without getting additional woocommerce plugins would be much appreciated.

Comment: From what I can see the add to cart form does include that enctype in the latest version of WooCommerce => "<form class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>"

Comment: The version of WooCommerce I am using is 3.2.4.  

This is what I see in Woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php

`<form class="woocommerce-cart-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">`

However, my code doesn't work even if I temporarily hard code the enctype into that form element.  Any other ideas on why the image is not posting to wp media?

Comment: Now I see where the enctype is set in woocommerce.  Directory single-product/add-to-cart/ and then in each product type there is a separate form element with it.